# Помогите с кодом json php

Tags: php, json, curl, https

Что с этим кодом не так почему не могу спарсить json:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://tui.taobao.com/recommend?itemid=528936847753&count=20&callback=jsonp293&appid=2338");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = substr($page, 62, -119);
$json = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($json);
```

Comment: И что конкретно не работает? Какие ошибки получаете? Иными словами, вопросу нужно больше конкретики

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Просто пустой ответ, не ошибки не ответа.

Comment: json_decode не работает. Нужно именно через curl?

Comment: Если вы получаете пустой ответ от целевого сайта, то JSON тут совсем не причем. А если под пустым ответом вы понимаете результат выдачи скрипта, то вам, для начала, стоит разобраться с уровнем вывода ошибок PHP (т.к. он их просто замалчивает)

Comment: @Doofy Да. валидный json ведь.

Comment: А вот и не валидный

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, потому что здесь валидный json: `$json = substr($page, 62, -119);` хранится не понятно почем функция `json_decode` не делает свою работу

Comment: @Doofy проверил http://jsonlint.com/ показывает валидный json

Comment: @mega94, раз так, то вам стоит выкинуть все, что относится к curl (ведь он тут не причем) из вопроса, и вместо этого привести ваш _валидный_ (в чем я сомневаюсь) JSON

Comment: А ну да, там же часть обрезается, валидная

Comment: Почему-то функция json_decode не работает. Возможно проблема в иероглифах (или кодировке(?)).

Comment: @Hardc0re хороший совет

Comment: @Hardc0re Как спарсить c иероглифами тогда?

Comment: @mega94, это всего лишь предположение, как исправить увы не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Дело действительно в иероглифах, помогла функция `iconv()`.

Comment: из какого в какой charset конвертировали этой функцией?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin `iconv("KOI8-U", "UTF-8",$json)` но иероглифы конвертировались на символы, зато спарсил нужные информации.